# Photoshop: how do you pick the original color from a layer that has effects on it?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

Let's say I have a layer that is originally white, but there's an effect that makes it gray. When I use the eyedropper tool on it, the color that's picked up is gray.

How do I make the color that is picked up **white**, which is the original color of the layer sans effects? Is this even possible?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

This can be done easily.

1) Layers > Layer Style > Hide All Effects. I binded this operation to Alt + Shift + Ctrl + D.

2) Use eyedropper.

3) Press Alt + Shift + Ctrl + D again to show up all effects.